# inarray 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, search

I have a 2d array

```
$list['1'][] ='23';
$list['1'][] ='24';
$list['1'][] ='25';
$list['1'][] ='26';
```

And a 1d array

```
$items={"23","24","36"};

following is right syntax for 1d array.

$items=array("23","24","36");
```

I want to check whether the $List['1'] values are inside the $items are not, if the items are not then store them into a new array

I tried

```
$different['1'][] = array_diff($items,$list['1']);
```

but if there are no difference it creates an array with key but empty value

$different['1]

```
['1'] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
    )
```

Comment: According to your current example result of array difference is correct because all the elements of $item1 is present in the array $list['1'].so what is the problem here???

Comment: Plz first fix the syntax error.

Comment: @Shades88 wanted to accept , but it needed 7 minutes

Comment: I did not mean that in immediate basis, but accept any previously posted questions that have got answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if($diff = array_diff($items,$list['1])){
     $different['1'][] = $diff;
}
```

This should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce this behaviour.

```
<?php
echo 'php: ', PHP_VERSION, "\n";
$list = array(1=>array());
$list[1][]=23;
$list[1][]=24;
$list[1][]=25;
$list[1][]=26;

$items = array(23,24);

var_dump(array_diff($items,$list[1]));
```

prints on my machine

```
php: 5.4.1
array(0) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$item = array('23','24');
foreach($list['1'] as $listItem) {
    if(!in_array($listItem, $item)) {
        $different['1'][] = $listItem;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$list['1'][] ='23';
$list['1'][] ='24'; 

$items=array("23","24");

$different['1'][] = array_diff($items,$list['1']);

var_dump($different['1']); // output: array(1) { [0]=> array(0) { } }

$different['1'] = array_diff($items,$list['1']);

var_dump($different['1']); // output: array(0) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      $list['1'][] ='23';
    $list['1'][] ='24';
    $list['1'][] ='25';
    $list['1'][] ='26';

    $items=array("23","24");

$different['1'][] = array_diff($list['1'],$items);
```

your arr_diff function's argument sequence was wrong. thats why it will give you null. try above code.

Answer (score 0):

Use for loop for every element in $list array and add following code in that loop

```
if(!in_array($list[1][0], $items)){
  array_push($items, $list[1][3]);
}

print_r($items);
```